# Singleton class for displaying iAds for iPhone

Tags: ios4, xcode4, iad, ios5

I have written a Singleton Class for managing iAds.The iAds pop up after 5 seconds of the user inactivity. The **idleTimerExceeded** call generate a notification to show the iAd. This code works fine for my requirements but since I am new to iOS development, my application sometimes hangs unexpectedly after integrating this code. This code results in lots of warnings etc. I would like to optimize my code in terms of memory and performance.

I would be very thankful for your kind suggestions and reviews.

Below is my code:

**iAdSingleton.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "iAd/iAd.h"

@interface iAdSingleton : UIViewController<ADBannerViewDelegate> {
    ADBannerView *adView;
    UIViewController *displayVC;
    NSTimer *idleTimer;
    BOOL isItFirstTime;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) ADBannerView *adView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *displayVC;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isItFirstTime;

+ (id) shareAdSingleton;
- (void) resetIdleTimer;
- (void) idleTimerExceeded;

@end
```

**iAdSingleton.m**

```
#import "iAdSingleton.h"

@implementation iAdSingleton

static iAdSingleton* _sharedAdSingleton = nil;

BOOL bannerVisible = NO;
BOOL controlAccessBannerVisibility = NO;
@synthesize adView, displayVC;
@synthesize isItFirstTime;

#define kMaxIdleTimeSeconds 5.0

+(id)sharedAdSingleton
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(!_sharedAdSingleton)
            _sharedAdSingleton = [[self alloc] init];
        return _sharedAdSingleton;
    }
    return nil;
}

+(id)alloc
{
    @synchronized([iAdSingleton class])
    {
        NSAssert(_sharedAdSingleton == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
        _sharedAdSingleton = [super alloc];
        return _sharedAdSingleton;
    }

    return nil;
}

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {

    /*                  Initialize The Parameters Over Here                  */

        //adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 0, 0)];
        adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
        self.adView.delegate=self;
        [self resetIdleTimer];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    displayVC = nil;
    if (adView) {
        [adView removeFromSuperview]; //Remove ad view from superview
        [adView setDelegate:nil];
        adView = nil;
    }
    [super dealloc];
}

-(UIViewController *)viewControllerForPresentingModalView
{
    return displayVC;
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner 
{
    banner.hidden = NO;
    if(!bannerVisible){
        NSLog(@"Banner Changes 1 - Purpose: Visibility");
        // [UIView beginAnimations:@"bannerAppear" context:NULL];
        // banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -100);
        // [UIView commitAnimations];
        bannerVisible = YES;
        controlAccessBannerVisibility = YES;

    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //NSLog(@"Unable to receive Ad.");
    NSLog(@"Banner Changes 2 - Purpose: Unable to Receive Ad.");
    banner.hidden = YES;
    if(bannerVisible){
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"bannerDisappear" context:NULL];
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 100);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        bannerVisible = NO;
    }
}

- (BOOL) bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    NSLog(@"Pause anything necessary");
    return YES;
}

- (void) bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"We now resume to normal operations");
}

- (void)resetIdleTimer {

    if (!idleTimer) {
        idleTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kMaxIdleTimeSeconds
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:NO] retain];
    }
    else {
        if (fabs([idleTimer.fireDate timeIntervalSinceNow]) < kMaxIdleTimeSeconds-1.0) {
            [idleTimer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:kMaxIdleTimeSeconds]];
            /*
             Notification: HideAd
             */

            NSLog(@"Notification Generated For HideAd");
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"HideAdBanner" object:nil userInfo:nil];

        }
    }
}

- (void)idleTimerExceeded {

    AppDelegate *appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (appDel.adVisible == NO) {
        NSLog(@"Notification Generated For ShowAd");

        /*
         Notification: ShowAd
         */

        if (controlAccessBannerVisibility == YES) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ShowAdBanner" object:nil userInfo:nil];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I am developing in iOS 5 and using xcode 4.2.

Comment: Once the iAd singleton is created does it continue to live for the rest of the life of your application?  Or do you release it and create it again later?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to have one instance of iAd for the application life.

Comment: @Maverick I think your singleton creation is not thread safe and optimized by memory point of view, try with dispatch_once_t onceToken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need. This code is thread safe as well as will not have any memory issue and warnings.

```
+ (iAdSingleton *) sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static iAdSingleton * __sharedInstance = nil;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        __sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return __sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, one quick question. What is the best approach to for managing iAds in a Tab Bar application?

Comment: Since, after integrating iAds, I experienced that my application performance have been slowed a bit and it takes a bit time switching between tabs.

Comment: I want my application to be fast with respect to performance wise.